# cannot call function from within ionic popup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic.

I have a function in my controller. I want to call that function from another function which has ionic popup. but, the function call does not happen.

Here is the code

Function with ionic popup

```
$scope.show = function() {
      var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({

        templateUrl: 'views/d.html',
        cssClass: 'custom-ipopup',
        title: 'Welcome to myapp',
        subTitle: 'enter username.',
        scope: $scope,
        buttons: [
          { text: '<b>Cancel</b>' },
          {
            text: 'Test',
            type: 'button-positive',
            onTap: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                scope.usernameCheck = usernameLookup();
                console.log(scope.usernameCheck);  //prints undefined      

             }
          }
       ]
  });

};
```

usernameLookup() function i am calling from $ioninPopup.show()'s onTap()

```
$scope.usernameLookup = function() {
            console.log('inside usernameLookup()');
            $scope.lookingDB = true;
            $scope.unamePresent = 3;
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: $rootScope.cred.url + '/api',
                params: {

                }
            }).success(function(d) {
                $scope.lookingDB = false;
                $scope.unamePresent = 1;
                return $scope.unamePresent 
            }).error(function(d) {
                $scope.lookingDB = false;
                $scope.unamePresent = 2;
                return $scope.unamePresent 
            });
        };
```

Can someone tell me why is it not calling usernameLookup() function? Both these methods are in same controller.

Comment: is `$ioninPopup` injected in controller ?

Comment: Yes, it is injected in controller

Comment: sorry, I had injected '$ionic'. Now replaced that with '$ionicPopup' and it works fine! :)

Comment: @Jyo Please mark this question as solved